# error using lstlisting inside minipage inside align*

Tags: listings, align, minipage

I am trying to use a `lstlisting` environment inside a `minipage`, *inside* an `align*` (fromo `amsmath`)... However, `lualatex` throws an error. This is the minimum working examp

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{listingsutf8}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
f(a\in A) &= x\\
f(x\in X) &= \begin{minipage}[t]{4cm}
\begin{lstlisting}[mathescape=true]
(let $m$=mean($X$)
    $g(m) \circ h(x)$)
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

The error is below:

```
! Argument of \lst@next has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
\par 
l.16 \end{align*}

? 
! Emergency stop.
<inserted text> 
\par 
l.16 \end{align*}
```

So, is there any way to do what I want? I'd like to define a function by cases, using `align*`, but with indented code on the right side

I'm not sure if it helps to mention that I'm typesetting the denotational semantics of a language, using some Lisp-like syntax on the right side of the equations defining semantic functions. A pseudo-example, formatted as plain text, follows.

```
      C[ v := e ]s = s[ E[e]/v ]
C[ some-command ]s = (let x=...
                         (if ...
                          then ...
                          else ...))
```

**edit**: As suggested by egreg, I tried the `tabbing` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{listingsutf8}
\lstset{%
    showstringspaces=false,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    commentstyle=\fontfamily{cmtt}\fontshape{it}\selectfont,
    frame=single
}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabbing}
$f(a\in A)$ = \= $x$\\
$f(x\in X)$ = \> (let $m$=mean($X$) in\\
\> $\;\;\;\;$    \= $g(m) \circ h(x)$)
\end{tabbing}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tabbing}
        $f(a\in A)$ = \= $x$\\
        $f(x\in X)$ = \> \begin{minipage}[t]{4cm}
\begin{lstlisting}[mathescape=true]
(let $m$=mean($X$) in:
    $g(m) \circ h(x)$)
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\end{tabbing}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

This is the result:

[image]

There are two attempts in the document. The first  seems cumbersone to typeset (and controlling indentation would be somewhat painful); the second is easier to type, but the first line of the `lstlisting` inside the  `minipage` isn't aligned  with the equation (I've included the frame in the `lstlisting` environment only to make the alignment clear).

Also, the equal signs don't seem to be aligned in both cases.

Is this easy to fix?

Comment: You can't use verbatim environments, including `lstlisting`, in the argument to another command; `align*` absorbs the environment's content as the argument to a command. But do you *really* need `lstlisting` for that?

Comment: I don't need `lstlisting`, but I need the code on the right side of the equation to be properly aligned -- and I'll be mixing texttt and math mode there. `lstlisting` makes that easy, but I'll use anything else that works!

Comment: I can think to `tabbing`; surely with `align` you can not “obey spaces and newlines”, because of how it works.

Comment: @egreg: see the edit... There are a few issues when I use `tabbing`, maybe those are easy to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `lstlisting` in the body of an `align*` environment, because it's the same as using it in the argument to a command, which is not allowed.

I suggest `tabbing`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
f(a\in A) &= x\\
f(x\in X) &=
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}\ttfamily
  \begin{tabbing}
    (let \= $m=\texttt{mean}(X)$ in\\
         \> $g(m) \circ h(x)$)
  \end{tabbing}
  \end{minipage}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

This takes advantage from the fact that a minipage that only encloses a `tabbing` environment is as wide as the widest line in the `tabbing`.

[image]

Comment: Perfect! And it seems, as I just found out, that there is a very clean way to control identation (see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15867/1416) )

Comment: @Jay Basically `tabbing` is thought for such applications. Search the site for other tricks with it.